# Mac peenhammer headaces

Tags: macos

I don't use ITunes. I don't use IMessenger. I don't use Mac's cloud service.  I don't want any of that stuff.

What I do get is an unending fusillade of dialog boxes that interrupt my work and that I am endlessly swatting away. Is there some way to restore peace in the valley??

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall iTunes, so that one is fixed.

I don't use iCloud either, but I have never had it ask me *anything*. Do this:
`Apple Menu` --> `Preferences` --> `iCloud` (first column, third row for me)
Make sure nothing is filled in, it should look like this:

[image]

I also do not use Apple's Messenger, and again it has never done a thing on my system. If you want, you can uninstall it by opening your applications directory and dragging it to the trash.